# Unable to Define label for Arc using JCanvas

Tags: javascript, jcanvas

I am using [JCanvas](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/) for drawing some arc. But I am not able to define label for arc.
Please suggest on how to define arc's label in Jcanvas.

Here is my arc code.

```
$('canvas').drawArc({
  strokeStyle: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 4,
  rounded: true,
  endArrow: true,
  arrowRadius: 15,
  arrowAngle: 90,
  x: 175, y: 175,
  start: 90,
  end: 160,
  radius: 150
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to create a text label to accompany your arc, you'll need to use the `drawText()` method ([documented here](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/docs/text/)) to place your desired text alongside the arc.

For instance:

```
$('canvas')
.drawArc({
  strokeStyle: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 4,
  rounded: true,
  endArrow: true,
  arrowRadius: 15,
  arrowAngle: 90,
  x: 175, y: 175,
  start: 90,
  end: 160,
  radius: 150
})
.drawText({
  fillStyle: 'red',
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  fontSize: 24,
  text: 'My arc label',
  x: 140, y: 320
});
```

The above code renders the following:

[image: jCanvas arc with label]